# Copy array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

when I copy the second element in the first element of my array, the reult is Nan expression. My code is:

```
for(var j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(j+1!==5){
            array[j] = array[j+1];
            }
        else{
            array[j]=x;
            }
    }
```

why?

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? can you provide your context. There is probably a much cleaner solution. Do you want to append x to the array?

Comment: I need a clearer description .

Comment: There is nothing in that code that would create a `NaN` value, are you sure one of your values wasn't already `NaN` before going into the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append an array element just call array.push:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
array.push(4) // array is now [1,2,3,4]
```

If you want a copy that has one more element than your original array then you go like this:

```
var arrayB = arrayA.slice() // copy arrayA
arrayB.push(4) // then append element to arrayB
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push